# I have 'standard access' to the permissions I need for a request on the Facebook Graph API, but error says I don't have required permissions

Tags: authentication, http, facebook-graph-api, oauth

When you register an app with the Facebook Graph API you by default have standard access to all permissions. Since at the moment it's just me testing my app, that should be enough. However when testing requests in Postman (and also the Graph API explorer!) I get the error message:

"(#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#page-public-metadata-access for details."

when making the request.

Why is this? Is it something to do with the 'roles' settings potentially?

As said, I've tried both in postman and the API explorer, and I'm pretty sure my request URI is well-formed, unless I'm missing something.

I know you can request advanced permissions but would be nice to test my app before I send it off for review.

Comment: _"Why is this?"_ - because you are confusing which permissions your app is _allowed_ to request from users, with actually _requesting_ the user to _grant_ your app those permissions. The "standard access" only means the former. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/permissions

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful, but is this really also true for  'Page Public Content Access' & 'Page Public Metadata Access'? This seems separate from permissions as you describe them, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Those are "features", and apply only on the app level. If you want to be able to use those, then you need to apply for them in your app review submission.

Comment: thank you! this is helpful. annoying that this is the case tho

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: i just want to get basic data from public pages using their ids to be able to display it. e.g. follower count data to get trend over time

Comment: Then you should develop & test your app with a page that your app user does have admin access to. Use their user token while you are developing the functionality. Querying the data from a public page you don't have admin access to, will only work after you submitted your app and got this feature approved.

Comment: And this feature will also require business validation.